# Perl: SSH Tail as File Handler

Tags: perl, ssh, tail

I am creating a log parser that has the ability to "stream" a log as it is written.
The log resides on a remote host, so I am creating a file handler using a combination of
SSH and tail.  The following works quite well, but I do have some questions regarding error handling.

- If the user doesn't enter the password for the SSH connection prior to the alarm delay expiring, the alarm will start triggering.  This leads to the console being cleared so it is not clear that the password needs to be entered.
- If i enter the wrong password, i still enable the alarm leading to screen clears, ect...

  ```
  Password:
  Password:
  Password:
  Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
  ```
- If i provide a log filename that doesn't exist, the code continues....

  ```
  tail: cannot open `/path_to_log/mylog.logXXXX' for reading: No such file or directory
  tail: no files remaining
  ```

So, my question is what is the best way add some additional error handling.  Alternatively, can the File::Tail module be used in combination with SSH, telnet, rlogin, etc to provide the same functionality?

Thanks!

```
    my $stopMsg = "Use CTRL+C to stop streaming at any time...\n";
    my $SSH = sprintf "ssh %s@%s tail -f %s | ", $user, $host, $log;

    printf "Log: %s\n", $log;
    printf "Handle: %s\n", $SSH;

    my $errMsg = sprintf "Couldn't establish SSH connection to \"%s\":",
                 $host;

    open my $pipe, $SSH or error( $errMsg );

    my $loadTime = time;

    printf $stopMsg;

    setSignalHandler( 'INT', sub{ stopAlarm( TRUE ); } );

    startAlarm( $delay,
                $interval,
                sub { system "clear"; $handler->( \@sysLogArr ); printf $stopMsg; } );

    while ( alarmHandlerSet() )
    {
        my $data = <$pipe>;

        next unless defined $data;

        mapSysLog( line   => $data,
                   arrRef => $logRef,
                   varRef => \%sysLogVars,
                   dbRef  => $dbRef );
    }

    clearSignalHandler( 'INT' );



sub error(@)
{
    my $color = "BOLD";
    $color = $CONFIG{errorPrinter} if ( $CONFIG{colorEnable} &&
                                        defined $CONFIG{errorPrinter} );

    color2PrinterRef( $color )->( "\nERROR: " );

    printf "%s\n", shift;
    printf "      %s\n", $_ foreach ( @_ );
    printf "Called From: %s::%d\n", (caller)[1], (caller)[2];
    printf "\n";

    exit EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Ummm... what do you mean by "error" in `open my $pipe, $SSH or error( $errMsg );`?  Do you mean `die`?

Comment: error accomplishes the same thing as die... But it prints the $errMsg, some other debug info, and then calls exit with failure code.

Comment: I've never heard of it, and neither `perldoc error` or `perldoc -f error` bring up any results.  Furthermore, trying `error` in a one-liner resulted in `Undefined subroutine &main::error called at...`.  Is this part of some module (it doesn't appear to be part of `Carp`)?  What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: Its a subroutine i wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [sftp_tail.pl](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SFTP-Foreign/blob/master/samples/sftp_tail.pl) sample included with [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign).

Comment: I will give this a try.  It looks like it will address my questions.